# Scrolling using cool-kitten-master framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I installed github.com/jalxob/cool-kitten to my site http://itee.lt/ However something is wrong with scrolling script: https://github.com/jalxob/cool-kitten/blob/master/js/scripts.js when I use top navigation bar and press on link, the text of pressed link doesn't change color. How to fix it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


$(window).stellar();

var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
slide = $('.slide');
button = $('.button');
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');


slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    }

});

mywindow.scroll(function () {
    if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
    }
});

function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
}



links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);

});


});
```

Comment: Please post your code here

Answer (score -1):

```
$(window).stellar();

var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
slide = $('.slide');
button = $('.button');
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');


slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    }

});

mywindow.scroll(function () {
    if (mywindow.scrollTop() <= 1) {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
    }
});

function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top + 1
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
}



links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);

});


});

javascript jquery html
```

Comment: Code only answer aren t considered goog, please comment the code

Comment: While you did make changes to the OP's submitted code, they're not obvious (I had to diff your answer with the post to make sure there were even changes).  Perhaps you could explain your changes, and include excerpts of their code, instead of duplicating a code dump.